# Configurar Tiimezone do MySQL no Spring Boot

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

**PROBLEMA**

Como faço para configurar o timezone do MySQL em um projeto utilizando o Spring Boot com tomcat?

**ERRO**

```
java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'Hora oficial do Brasil' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
    a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa Tarde, tudo bem?

Insira a linha abaixo no **application.properties** :

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/seubanco?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC
```

não esqueça de alterar o **seubanco** para o nome do seu banco de dados (schema)

Comment: Deu certo. Obrigado.